Dotted box around algorithm
We need the box with dotted rules around the algorithm. I tried using
\usepackage[boxruled]{algorithm2e}. The rule comes as solid rule instead of dotted what I required.
Can you please check and advise any option to get this achived. Thanks!

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You could nest your algorithms inside of tcolorbox, I'd suggest creating an environment for that.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalgo}{O{}}
  {%
    \begin{tcolorbox}
      [
        floatplacement=tbp, float,
        enhanced, sharp corners, frame hidden, borderline={1pt}{0pt}{dotted},
        #1
      ]
      \begin{algorithm}[H]
  }
  {%
      \end{algorithm}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  }

\begin{document}
This is some text.
\begin{myalgo}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeXe}

  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
      }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
      }
    }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{myalgo}

This is some more text.
\end{document}


